# Inaccurate Job search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, search

When I make this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=ios), I find the top 4 results are not even remotely related to what I searched for.  Only the 5th result actually contains the tag that I searched for.
Why is that?

Comment: [ios] search example seems to be fixed, but location based search still has same issue. Only the 5th result is correct in [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?l=United+Kingdom)

Answer (score -4):

First, you can use the syntax `[tagname]` to search by tag. For instance, here's a search for [jobs with the ios tag](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=%5Bios%5D).

If you omit the brackets, a search by *keyword* is performed.

Now for some explanation on the behavior you're observing:

- First, our backing search engine (ElasticSearch) returns jobs for the search "ios" that don't actually mention iOS at all. That's worth investigating. **Edit**: This is now fixed.
- Second, we re-sort jobs returned by ElasticSearch using the matching algorithm. That's to personalize your results, i.e. take advantage of your job preferences, Stack Overflow activity, etc. When we do so, we assume that ElasticSearch only returned *relevant* results, which is not the case here.

We have plans to have a sorting mechanism that leverages *both* the ElasticSearch engine *and* the matching algorithm. Should be ready in 6 to 8 weeks.