# Un-Intelligent Ranking of Job Search Results

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, search, tag-search

When I make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-ios) search,  50% of the first 4 search results are non-iOS jobs that happen to use the `[ios]` tag, but I can see where the problem is.

Would it be possible to sort the search results by tag order?  In other words, if I search for `[ios]` tag, then give me the search results with `[ios]` as the first tag, then `[ios]` as the 2nd tag, etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

Aurélien addresses some of your points in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343677/inaccurate-job-search-results/343687#343687). In short; we're working on merging matches sort with the relevance we get from Elastic. It's not *exactly* what you asked for but there are better measures to indicate whether a job is actually iOS or not so I've marked this as [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).