# Putting "Developer" In The Job Search- Sort Of Breaks It

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs, search

I was doing some research on job listings based on developer language. After going through several different job sites, I came here and started typing in the same search keywords I had been using thus far:

- Python Developer, 2682 results
- Swift Developer, 2674 results
- C++ Developer, 2678 results

I found the close proximity of results to be odd due to the fact that the number of results on other job sites were not so dramatically close; quite the contrary, depending on the site. Then I realized that the resulting jobs had nothing to do with the language and *everything* to do with the keyword "Developer". So, I omitted what I assumed to be the issue and searched:

- Python, 824 results
- Swift, 126 results
- C++, 482 results

Ah, now that's what I was expecting. Not only were the quantities of each job search different, each job posting was significantly more relevant to the language being queried.

With that said, I think this could be an issue. I noticed a similar trend if you used keywords in your search like "engineer" or "programmer". I understand that, this being Stack Overflow, it should be obvious as to what kind of job someone would be seeking. Regardless, it may be of use to others to clean up the search algorithm such that the search isn't absolutely ruined by a coffee-deprived job seeker :)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343677/inaccurate-job-search-results?rq=1

Comment: Isn't that how most search engines behave? If you look for multiple keywords, it usually looks for results containing any of those keywords, but it will usually rank those with both keywords higher than those with any of the keywords. The closer the proximity of those keywords, it usually ranks even higher. Searching for `"Python developer"` might provide the wanted results, in that case, [only 52 results appear](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=%22Python+developer%22).

Comment: @g00glen00b By adding quotes, you make it a different search altogether (doesn't match _we're looking for a developer that's skilled with python_). [Python AND Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=Python+AND+developer) returns 738 results. That's more likely the desired result.

Comment: @g00glen00b Searching “Python Developer” on other job sites brought up jobs that included being a developer with the python language. On SO, the same search brings up mostly jobs for .NET, JavaScript, and having nothing to do with python.

Comment: @8protons I believe you, I'm just saying that I think that's how many search engines work. If you Google "python developer", you'll eventually going to find result that only match "Developer" and might perhaps encounter a result about a ".NET developer". But as mentioned before, searching for `Python AND developer` or `"Python Developer"` might return the results you're seeking for.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Even though that `Python AND Developer` is also a different search altogether, you're probably right that that's the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the only solution is to allow the user to add their desired boolean operators in their query (and explain what's available).

You could try to categorise each term so that e.g. it separated all the languages into a union and intersected it with a union of all the other terms. That's probably going to give the expected query most of the time, assuming people would make separate queries for separate types of job (i.e. not "Java Programmer or Unity Games Artist").